# Geometry nodes to make branches not appear on the bottom section of tree trunk

Tags: objects, faces, geometry-nodes, vector

I am porting this YouTube tutorial to the Blender 3 nodes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzIdcGdGXLM. I have successfully ported mostly everything over to Blender 3 up until about the 33 minute mark. the part that I'm having trouble with is getting the branches to appear only on the top approximately 3/4 of the tree trunk. This is what the video looks like at this point:
[image]

This is what my file looks like at this point:
[image]

It's substantially the same as the video tutorial except for the fact that I can't find geometry nodes in Blender 3 to mimic the attribute math less than and point separate nodes to achieve the desired effect. Here's a Blender file with my tree simulation:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-O5sJqsRXosWqO739IZekhKhUQXWegXQ/view?usp=sharing

Can someone please show me how to get the branches to not populate on the lower section of the tree trunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Attribute Math node is no longer necessary because the ordinary Math node now accepts fields as inputs and produces a field as output. The Point Separate node has been replaced with the more general Separate Geometry node.

Here’s an example of how the new nodes might be used together in a configuration similar to the one in the video:

[image]